# How to write xpath for this code?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

This is my Html code please give me suggestions for how to select the WebElement using xpath or css selector?

```
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-desktop"/>
    <span>Masters</span>
    <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"/>
    </a>


 Thanks
 srinu
```

Comment: which element you want to select?

Comment: <span>Masters</span>

Comment: I have mentioned the answer below.. please tried with same and get back to me if still facing any issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Try below Xpath

```
//span[contains(.,'Masters')]
```

OR

```
 //a[@class='dropdown-toggle']//span[contains(.,'Masters')]
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: `<span>Masters</span>` is not child of `i`, its a sibling.

Comment: Her code is not formateed well.. so it's a wild guess that it's a child .... that's why I have mentioned the 2nd alternative Xpath as well..

Comment: u r right but i want know the logic behind that write this type of xpath especially why did u use (.,) in contains method can u explain

Comment: //span means it will find all the span from you HTML DOM .. it happens because of // ... contains function will filter all those result with the element having the sub-string ... like here in your case "Masters" is sub-string ... now suppose if there is more string present with same sub-string then xpath will return you that as well :)

Comment: `<i />` is self closing tag, its like `<i></i>`

Comment: //a[@class='dropdown-toggle']//span[contains(.,'Masters')] ... guy i think you are smart enough to understand this

Comment: I was talking only about your first xpath

Comment: oh ya ... you are right .. I missed that .. thanks for point it out

Comment: suppose there are two elements with name 'Masters' so what should i do?

Comment: It's totally depend on your HTML structure .. Let take a example of my 2nd xpath .. if your another Master text having the same tag as a and class as drop... then it that case only my 2nd xpath will return you 2nd element as well .. for that you need to use List<WebElement> and then you need to use it accroding to your requirement

Comment: For contains ->   http://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html

Comment: For list example:- http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8029/how-to-iterate-a-list-of-webelements-and-print-the-values-one-by-one-to-perform ... We are using findelements in that case .. dont use findelement

Comment: Some advance xpath tricks :- http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/xpath-tutorial-for-selenium

Comment: Thank you so much ..Shubham Jain, i am searching for this so far http://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html